# Increase columns width in Silverlight DataGrid to fill whole DG width

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, width

I have a DataGrid Control which is bound to a SQL Table.

The XAML Code is:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dg_sql_data" 
                       Grid.Row="1" 
                       Visibility="Collapsed" 
                       Height="auto" 
                       Margin="0,5,5,5"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                       AlternatingRowBackground="Aqua"
                       Opacity="80"
                       >
    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Latitude" Binding="{Binding lat}" />
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Longitude" Binding="{Binding long}" />
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding time}" />
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```

Is it possible increase the single columns sizes to fill out the complete width of the datagrid?

Thanks,
Henrik

**Edit: 
Columns with "*" as width are coming with the Silverlight SDK 4.**

Comment: I've tried the `Width="*"` in Silverligth 5, and I enounter [this[(http://stackoverflow.com/q/5652195/75500) issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

```
    void dg_sql_data_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid myDataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        // Do not change column size if Visibility State Changed
        if (myDataGrid.RenderSize.Width != 0)
        {
            double all_columns_sizes = 0.0;
            foreach (DataGridColumn dg_c in myDataGrid.Columns)
            {
                all_columns_sizes += dg_c.ActualWidth;
            }
            // Space available to fill ( -18 Standard vScrollbar)
            double space_available = (myDataGrid.RenderSize.Width - 18) - all_columns_sizes;
            foreach (DataGridColumn dg_c in myDataGrid.Columns)
            {
                dg_c.Width = new DataGridLength(dg_c.ActualWidth + (space_available / myDataGrid.Columns.Count));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the picture link is broken

Answer (score 8):

### **Tested only in WPF, not in Silverlight:**

I set up in WPF 3.5 SP1 and it works perfect, no guaranties about Silverlight, but if it works it's indeed charming.

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding}" Width="*" />
```

Comment: Awesome! Works in WPF, not sure about Silverlight

Comment: This has a nasty bug, though - if you have a column like this and also right-aligned content in RowDetails, it would not move left when the grid width is decreased.

Comment: Yes, this sux, I also experienced it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an [attached property](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SLDataGridProperties) for the DataGrid that lets you do this in XAML:

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"  
    x:Class="GridProperties.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:gp="clr-namespace:GridProperties">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <data:DataGrid gp:GridEx.StarColumn="2">
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1"/>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2"/>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3"/>
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Henrik P's answer, this solution simply straightens out the bug with `Width='*'` so that you can set any column to be proportional like you can on a grid:

```
    private void DgSQLDataSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myDataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

        // Do not change column size if Visibility State Changed
        if (myDataGrid.RenderSize.Width == 0) return;

        double totalActualWidthOfNonStarColumns = myDataGrid.Columns.Sum(
            c => c.Width.IsStar ? 0 : c.ActualWidth);

        double totalDesiredWidthOfStarColumns = 
            myDataGrid.Columns.Sum(c => c.Width.IsStar ? c.Width.Value : 0);

        if ( totalDesiredWidthOfStarColumns == 0 ) 
            return;  // No star columns

        // Space available to fill ( -18 Standard vScrollbar)
        double spaceAvailable = (myDataGrid.RenderSize.Width - 18) - totalActualWidthOfNonStarColumns;

        double inIncrementsOf = spaceAvailable/totalDesiredWidthOfStarColumns;

        foreach (var column in myDataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if ( !column.Width.IsStar ) continue;

            var width = inIncrementsOf * column.Width.Value;
            column.Width = new DataGridLength(width, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        }
    }
```

I liked Henrik's answer but needed two columns to fill the extra space, like a grid.

Answer (score 1):

In silverlight 4:  simply set ColumnWidth="*" on the DataGrid

```
<data:DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" />
```

Comment: I tried that with a simple DataGrid (I'm trying to make last column occupy the available space), but I encounter [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5652195/75500) issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it programmatically:

```
var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
col.Width = new DataGridLength(100, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);                        
Grid1.Columns.Add(col);
```