# Silverlight DataGrid Annoying Extra column on right side

Tags: silverlight

I am adding dynamic columns in silverlight data grid.And I want to assign width for columns such a way that it covers entire grid width.

I tried this solution mentioned but still it is adding one extra column and than splits remaining columns in same width.

[Increase columns width in Silverlight DataGrid to fill whole DG width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894991/increase-columns-width-in-silverlight-datagrid-to-fill-whole-dg-width)

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Add Width="*" in the last column of the datagrid.

Answer (score 4):

In silverlight 4: simply set ColumnWidth="*" on the DataGrid

```
<data:DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with a Custom Attached Property.  Code is [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SLDataGridProperties).