# Silverlight - DataGrid in Scrollviewer, Column.Width="*" makes datagrid take several screen-widths

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, scrollviewer

When I have the following setup, the last column having a width of * causes the datagrid to create huge horizontal scrollbars (extends grid to several widths of the screen). I'm not really sure why this is, but I really need a way to avoid that. I don't want to have to "simulate" column's with * lengths.

edit: Apparently I'm not the only one who noticed this.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559644/silverlight-4-datagrid-star-column-width

Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer Padding="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  >
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dg"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Binding = new Binding("A"), Header = "A" });
        dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Binding = new Binding("B"), Header = "B" });
        dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Binding = new Binding("C"), Header = "C" });
        dg.Columns[2].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        dg.ItemsSource = new[] 
        {
            new I { A = "SAF", B = "SAF", C = "SAF" },
            new I { A = "SAF", B = "SAF", C = "SAF" },
            new I { A = "SAF", B = "SAF", C = "SAF" }
        };
    }

    public class I
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: why you put datagrid inscrollviwer?

Comment: I'm working on a large application and the grid is inside a frame, which is inside of a scrollviewer. There are cases (such as if you have lots of columns that actually take up space) where you would want the scrolling behavior. 

This is a reproducible sample. Rest assured, if I have it in a scrollviewer, it needs to be in a scrollviewer, and if it didn't need to be in a scrollviewer, I'd remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove

dg.Columns[2].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

the problem should go away. Can I ask why you want the last column to take the rest of the space? The column actually knows to resize itself properly to fit its cell size and column header size.

Also, if you don't specify the column's width, then you don't really need a scrollviewer to scroll and see all the columns. The datagrid has a scrollviewer built in and when there are columns out of the screen the horizontal scrollbar will apear.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: My original post specifies that this is exactly the behavior I'm seeking. I want my last column to take up the remainder of space. 

1) I think this should be the default behavior because otherwise you're really just wasting space
2) In this instance my last column is something like an error/comment column which will have a message.

So removing that really doesn't help, but thank you for your reply.

Comment: Are you saying your last column is very long so it needs to take the rest of the space?

Comment: I have created a sample project and put it in http://cid-f9ac8aa3f6afdcc3.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/datagridlastcolumnstar.zip If you find it still doesn't do what you need then please igonre it.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but this behavior is slightly different from what I am trying to accomplish. In a simple sense it's analogous, but actually I'm trying to combine this with a details template, which doesn't stretch past the end of the last column.

For consistency, I would like the last column to extend to the end of the available area regardless of whether the last column currently has any long values.

Comment: sorry me running out of ideas... :(

Comment: @Xin Hi, I'm experiencing the same issue, except that I declared the DataGrid in XAML setting the last col width to `*`. I experience the same behavior as the OP. See screenshots: [DataGrid](http://i.imgur.com/TP7B7.png), [Middle of page](http://i.imgur.com/fNeHK.png), any suggestions?

Comment: @Shimmy, How about disabling the horizontal scroll bar of the outer `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: @Xin, no, in my sample there aint no scrollbar, it's from one of the parents' grid. If I set the grid max width to 100 no scroll bars appear. the problem is the datagrid, and only when i set last col to *

Comment: @Shimmy, on your first screenshot there is a horizontal scroll bar, which does it belong to? I thought it was a ScrollViewer.

Comment: @Xin, yes it is, but it's not declared. It's built in.

Comment: @Shimmy, you can disable it by adding this piece of code in your ScrollViewer, `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`.

Comment: @Xin, again, I haven't declared any ScrollViewers in my page/views, if there is a ScrollViewer it's from one of the controls that has a ScrollViewer built-in. Is there a way I can find out whom this ScrollViewer blongs to?

Comment: @Shimmy, you can try Silverlight Spy.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put a maxwidth on the scrollviewer?  otherwise width is defaulted to auto and maxwidth is infinity