# WPF DataGrid column gobbles up space faster than Ms Pac-Man

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer, column-width

I'm trying to get a `DataGrid` column to fill up the remaining space for the `DataGrid`, when the parent control contains a `ScrollViewer` without having the column take far more `Width` than the top level window.

As shown in the two images below, the datagrid itself behaves as desired if the `DataGrid` columns are set with `Width="Auto"`.  The `DataGrid` stretches to fill the width in the parent control, and allows the `ScrollViewer` to kick in as the control is sized down.  However there is a lot of wasted space in the `DataGrid`.

[image: No Scrolling]

[image: Scrolling]

However, if I use `Width="*"` for the description column, the width of the control becomes significantly wider than the top level window.

[image]

There is a nearly identical question (unanswered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652195/silverlight-datagrid-in-scrollviewer-column-width-makes-datagrid-take-seve).

Below is some sample XAML for the elements within the scrollviewer.  I tried setting the `MaxWidth` of the `DataGrid` based on some parent width, which would reign in the space gobbling column, but that approach hasn't worked so far.  I could hard code a `MaxWidth`, but I want the `DataGrid` to stretch as much as possible to the visible area.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}">
    <Grid MinWidth="600" MinHeight="400">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource LabelHeader}" Content="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource EntityIndexNameInput}" Content="{Binding EntityIndexNameLabel, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource DescriptionInput}" Content="{Binding DescriptionLabel, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ToolTip="{Binding EntityIndexNameValidationMessage, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding EntityIndexName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="255" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Loaded="TextBox_Loaded" />
        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
            <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource IsPrimaryKeyIndexInput}" ToolTip="{Binding IsPrimaryKeyIndexValidationMessage}" Content="{Binding IsPrimaryKeyIndexLabel, Mode=OneWay}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPrimaryKeyIndex}" />
            <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource IsUniqueIndexInput}" ToolTip="{Binding IsUniqueIndexValidationMessage}" Content="{Binding IsUniqueIndexLabel, Mode=OneWay}" IsChecked="{Binding IsUniqueIndex}" />
        </WrapPanel>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" ToolTip="{Binding DescriptionValidationMessage, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="120" MaxLength="2000" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource labels}, Path=PropertiesHeader}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid Margin="2">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Path=ActualSize.Width}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <lib:BindableDataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource labels}, Path=EntityIndexPropertyNameHeader}" DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName" SelectedValuePath="PropertyID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PropertyID}" ItemsSource="{Binding EntityDataProperties}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource labels}, Path=OrderHeader}" Binding="{Binding PropertyOrder, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource labels}, Path=DescriptionHeader}" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5">
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Content="{Binding UpdateButtonLabel}"></Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" Content="{Binding ResetButtonLabel}"></Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding DefaultsCommand}" Content="{Binding DefaultsButtonLabel}"></Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding CloseConfirmCommand}" Content="{Binding CloseButtonLabel}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Any other approaches to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to prevent the content of the ScrollViewer from being too wide:

```
<ScrollViewer ...>
    <Grid MinWidth="600" MinHeight="400"
          MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                    AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}">
        ...
```

Comment: +1 Perfect, thanks Vlad!  I was almost there with the MaxWidth binding.